# Duplicate information in a rest architecture

Tags: spring, rest, spring-restcontroller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/medicalcontacts/{medicalContactId}", method =RequestMethod.PUT)
public void updateMedicalContact(@RequestBody @Valid final MedicalContactDto medicalContactDto, @PathVariable("medicalContactId") long medicalContactId){
     medicalContactService.save(medicalContactDto);
}
```

In my object MedicalContactDto, I have the medicalContactId, so for me it's seem like we duplicate information, but url allow to 
define what we do...

I don't passe the medicalContactId value to the method...

Is it the normal way to manage this kind of case?

Comment: I would use the id in the url and ignore the id in the dto.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that correct way is to having it like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/medicalcontacts/{medicalContactId}", method =RequestMethod.PUT)
public void updateMedicalContact(@RequestBody @Valid final MedicalContactDto medicalContactDto, @PathVariable("medicalContactId") long medicalContactId){
     medicalContactDto.setMedicalContactId(medicalContactId);
     medicalContactService.save(medicalContactDto);
}
```

The reason is that using PUT on some resource means you want to change it.

If you using it like before, you can have some troubles, when accidentally the medicalContactId in address and in object differs. And it would be one of hard-finding bug.

Comment: @roberttrudel - this is not how it works :). Right now, you know you are using it "right", that you are using right id and right medicalContactDto. However in future, you can easily switch some variables.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@PathVariable` in this API. Use only the `MedicalContactDto`.

if you remove `medicalContactId` from `MedicalContactDto`, then you cannot reuse this DTO elsewhere.

So my take is to remove the id from the `@PathVariable`, UNLESS you want to do some validation based on PathVariable before you come to the Controller

eg: Below case

In an Interceptor *[control comes to interceptor before the controller]*

```
Map pathVariables = (Map) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);
String contactId= (String) pathVariables.get("medicalContactId");
// do some validation and prevent the control from even going to controller.
```

If you still want to retain the pathvariable, use that value to set the `medicalContactId` of the `MedicalContactDto`.

Comment: if i remove pathvariable my url will change... will have same call for post and put

Comment: ok, understood, in that case, don't remove the path variable, retain both of your arguments and code this `medicalContactDto.setMedicalContactId(medicalContactId);`